# validate multiple URL input fields

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have following Javascript validation function that should check that the URL posted to my php are OK - if not display a message to correct the entry. 
I must have done a mistake somewhere because it is not working and my console.log says: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
validateFormbasic.html:12
onsubmitbasic.html:24:95
Could you tell me how to fix it please? Thanks a lot!

```
<form method="POST" name="inputLinks" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
<input type="text" name="web1" id="url1" placeholder="domain.com">
<input type="text" name="web2" id="url2" placeholder="domain.com">
<input type="text" name="web3" id="url3" placeholder="domain.com">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Done" />   
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateURL(web1, web2, web3) {
var reurl = /^(http[s]?:\/\/){0,1}(www\.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\.]{0,1}/;
return reurl.test(url);
}

function validateForm()
{
// Validate URL
var url = $("#url1", "#url2", "#url3").val();
if (validateURL(url)) { } else {
    alert("Please enter a valid URL, remember including http://");
}
return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: did you include jQuery in your page ?

Comment: Are you sure that by they time `validateForm` is called jQuery has been loaded?

Comment: I have following in my <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

Comment: The below answer seems to work for me, be sure to accept the answer if it does for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alberto's comment mentions, it looks like jQuery isn't loaded at the point of calling the function.  It also looks to me as if you're syntax for selecting the URL values isn't quite right.

I would use something along the lines of:

```
<form method="POST" name="inputLinks">
<input type="text" name="web1" id="url1" class="url" placeholder="domain.com" />
<input type="text" name="web2" id="url2" class="url"  placeholder="domain.com" />
<input type="text" name="web3" id="url3" class="url"  placeholder="domain.com" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Done" />   
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

        function validateURL(url) {
            var reurl = /^(http[s]?:\/\/){0,1}(www\.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\.]{0,1}/;
            return reurl.test(url);
        }

        $('form').submit(function(e){

            var isValid = true;

            $('.url').each(function(){
               isValid = validateURL($(this).val());
               return isValid;
            });

            if (!isValid){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("Please enter a valid URL, remember including http://");
            }

        });

    });

</script>
```

**Update**

[Demo JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevbaister/gqKdn/)

Comment: You are right, there was problem with the syntax of my original code, thanks!